# $_POST into Array => $variable

Tags: php, arrays, post

I've done this before but for some reason I cannot get it working now!

Is:

```
$_POST = array(
    'num1'  =>  $num1,
    'num2'  =>  $num2
);
```

More or less this?:

```
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
```

It doesn't work for some reason?

I have a HTML form with 
I'm trying to assign $_POST['num1'] to the variable $num1.
Thanks,

Comment: The first case sets the value the 2nd case gets it. But the value may not be getting assigned to the same variables in the 2nd case. `$num1` from 1st case is not same as `$num1` from 2nd case.

Comment: What is your problem/question ? What is your goal?

Comment: what is your question? what is expected? and what is the value of $num1 and $num2 in the array?

Comment: I have a HTML form with <input type="text" name="num1" />
I'm trying to assign $_POST['num1'] to the variable $num1.

Comment: then why you are sowing your array like that? according to your html code it will be like second one automatically in your question. also show your html code also

Comment: Perhaps you could show the <form> tag?  Are you using POST or GET?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that `$_POST` is a sort of 'reserved array'. So do not use it as a 'custom array'. It generates automatically when a form "posts" its fields' values.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <input name="num1" value="num1_value" />
   <input name="num2" value="num2_value" />
</form>
```

Then your `action.php` takes form's values as an array called `$_POST`.

Then now, I might answer you that redeclaring `$_POST` as an Array sounds purposeless:

```
$_POST = array(...);
```

However, you might use `$_POST` in this manner into your action.php file, at least treating it as an Array:

```
$default = <your_default_value>;
if (isset($_POST)){
  $num1 = array_key_exists ('num1', $_POST) ? $_POST['num1'] : $default;
  $num2 = array_key_exists ('num2', $_POST) ? $_POST['num2'] : $default;
}
```

It is not a final solution. Take it as a modest `$_POST` explanation.